# JSP String encoding issue

Tags: jsp, encoding, utf-8

I have a code like this in my JSP page

```
 <% String value = function();
    System.out.println(value);
 %>
```

I am pretty sure my function() returns a string which is viewable. However when I run this on server the printed text i can see in my console is a bunch of question marks. Im sure this is an encoding issue but not able to figure it out. I tried converting the string from from unicode to iso-8859-1 and vice versa but it was of no help. the encoding of my html page is UTF-8 can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than printing to the console, why don't you return the text to the browser, for example:

```
<% 
    String value = function();
    out.println(value);
%>
```

Use this page directive in your JSP to ensure the page encoding is UTF-8:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
```